# Check if column exists in Nested JSON

Tags: java, jsonpath

Below is my sample JSON

```
{
      "_id":{
         "$oid":"1564t8re13e4ter86"
      },
      "object":{
         "shop":"shop1",
         "domain":"Divers",
         "sell":[
            {
               "location":{
                  "zipCode":"58000",
                  "city":"NEVERS"
               },
               "properties":{
                  "description":"ddddd!!!!",
                  "id":"f1re67897116fre87"
               },
               "employee":[
                  {
                     "name":"employee1",
                     "id":"245975"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"employee2",
                     "id":"458624"
                  }
               ],
               "customer":{
                  "name":"Customer1",
                  "custid":"test_réf"
               }
               "preference":"talking"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

In the above sample i would like to know if this particular column exists in the $.object.sell.preference exists , as in most cases it is not existing which is leading to failure.

Also i am good if there is any option i can set to get null or blank as return when using readcontext.read($...)

Thanks in Advance

Regards

Comment: You might want to use **JSONObject** to parse your json and use its `has(String key)`method to check if a key exists in this Json or not. If it does exists, just retrieve it and set it to the desired valued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE: I'm referring in java

Yes, it is possible to check using jsonObject.has() method.
Suppose you have response variable in which you have full JSON

You can proceed it like this

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
 JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONObject("object").getJSONArray("sell");
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    if (jsonObject1.has("preference")) {
        //  Exist
    } else {
        //Not Exist
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
bool(json['object']['sell'][0]["preference"])
```

it will return false if empty and vice versa

Comment: Hi @JaySabir  - Let me try on the same. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Hi , Can the column names be dynamically built to check ?